# Backup Sharepoint Office 365 Page

Tags: backup, office-web-apps

The sys admin at my organization set up a SharePoint site using Office 365.
I've created a new Page with some documentation which I would like to back up somehow.
I've looked around and I've been unable to find any clear way (that corresponds to what I'm seeing on my version of SharePoint) to export, back up, off-board or save offline.

How can I backup or export a page or site in SharePoint Office 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 3rd party backup application (Veeam, AvePoint, etc. -- look for a SharePoint Online backup tool) or you can instead rely on Version History to roll back any changes as well as the SharePoint site recycle bin which stores deleted items for 93 days unless a Site Collection Administrator manually purges the content.